# what is the best way to update in mongodb from array object json?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a json file which has data like this

```
[
   {"person_id": "3455666", "person_app": "bjjiu877y"},
   {"person_id": "5633444", "person_app": "rh5556ggg"},
   {"person_id": "9866654", "person_app": "66he4455"},
   ......
]
// length array might 100k - 200k
```

and in person_collection , i don't have field `person_app`, and the identifier in person_collection is `person_id`

i want t update person_collection doc to has person_app

i was tried with script in js file with

```
for( let {person_id, person_app} of dataFromJson) {
  db.person_collection.update({person_id}, {"set": {person_app}})
}
```

i take long time to update and i might dont know if all data is updated, i just want to make sure all data updated at all

is that any way to update this large data to know that all data updated? and to make it fast?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should run a [Bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/), for example like this:

```
var operations = [];
var i = 0;

for (let { person_id, person_app } of dataFromJson) {
   operations.push({ updateOne: { filter: person_id, update: { $set: person_app } } });
   i++;
   if (i % 10000 == 0) {
      db.person_collection.bulkWrite(operations, { ordered: false });
      operations = [];
   }
}
if (operations.length > 0)
   db.person_collection.bulkWrite(operations, { ordered: false });
```